# Shopify Android API pulling product images to ListView

Tags: android, json, listview, android-imageview, shopify

Im making an app for a Shopify website using the [Shopify Android API](https://github.com/Shopify/mobile-buy-sdk-android) and currently the sample app just lists each product in a simple text ListView. Can anyone aid me in trying to get the images and display them next to the text in the ListView. Any help would be amazing, sorry kinda new to this.

ProductListActivity.java

```
public class ProductListActivity extends SampleListActivity {

static final String EXTRA_COLLECTION_ID = "ProductListActivity.EXTRA_COLLECTION_ID";

private String collectionId;
private ProductDetailsTheme theme;
private boolean useProductDetailsActivity;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState, R.layout.product_list_activity);

    setTitle(R.string.choose_product);

    useProductDetailsActivity = true;
    theme = new ProductDetailsTheme(getResources());

    Intent intent = getIntent();
    if (intent.hasExtra(EXTRA_COLLECTION_ID)) {
        collectionId = intent.getStringExtra(EXTRA_COLLECTION_ID);
    }


            theme.setStyle(ProductDetailsTheme.Style.LIGHT);

            theme.setShowProductImageBackground(false);
        }



@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    // If we haven't already loaded the products from the store, do it now
    if (listView.getAdapter() == null && !isFetching) {
        isFetching = true;
        showLoadingDialog(R.string.loading_data);

        Callback<List<Product>> callback = new Callback<List<Product>>() {
            @Override
            public void success(List<Product> products, Response response) {
                isFetching = false;
                dismissLoadingDialog();
                onFetchedProducts(products);
            }

            @Override
            public void failure(RetrofitError error) {
                isFetching = false;
                onError(error);
            }
        };

        if (collectionId != null) {
            getSampleApplication().getProducts(collectionId, callback);
        } else {
            getSampleApplication().getAllProducts(callback);
        }
    }
}


/**
 * Once the products are fetched from the server, set our listView adapter so that the products appear on screen.
 *
 * @param products
 */
private void onFetchedProducts(final List<Product> products) {
    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            List<String> productTitles = new ArrayList<String>();
            for (Product product : products) {
                productTitles.add(product.getTitle());
            }

            listView.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<>(ProductListActivity.this, R.layout.simple_list_item, productTitles));
            listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                    if (useProductDetailsActivity) {
                        launchProductDetailsActivity(products.get(position));
                    } else {
                        createCheckout(products.get(position));
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    });
}

private void launchProductDetailsActivity(Product product) {
    getSampleApplication().launchProductDetailsActivity(this, product, theme);
}

/**
 * When the user selects a product, create a new checkout for that product.
 *
 * @param product
 */
private void createCheckout(final Product product) {
    showLoadingDialog(R.string.syncing_data);

    getSampleApplication().createCheckout(product, new Callback<Checkout>() {
        @Override
        public void success(Checkout checkout, Response response) {
            dismissLoadingDialog();
            onCheckoutCreated(checkout);
        }

        @Override
        public void failure(RetrofitError error) {
            onError(error);
        }
    });
}

/**
 * If the selected product requires shipping, show the list of shipping rates so the user can pick one.
 * Otherwise, skip to the discounts activity (gift card codes and discount codes).
 *
 * @param checkout
 */
private void onCheckoutCreated(Checkout checkout) {
    if (checkout.isRequiresShipping()) {
        startActivity(new Intent(ProductListActivity.this, ShippingRateListActivity.class));
    } else {
        startActivity(new Intent(ProductListActivity.this, DiscountActivity.class));
    }

}

}
```

SampleListActivity.java

```
public class SampleListActivity extends SampleActivity {

protected ListView listView;
protected boolean isFetching;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    onCreate(savedInstanceState, R.layout.list_activity);
}

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState, int layoutId) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(layoutId);
    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_view);
    isFetching = false;
}

}
```

SampleActivity.java

```
public class SampleActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private static final String LOG_TAG = SampleActivity.class.getSimpleName();

// The amount of time in milliseconds to delay between network calls when you are polling for Shipping Rates and Checkout Completion
protected static final long POLL_DELAY = 500;

protected Handler pollingHandler;

private ProgressDialog progressDialog;
private boolean webCheckoutInProgress;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    pollingHandler = new Handler();

    initializeProgressDialog();
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    // If we are being launched by a url scheme, check the scheme and retrieve the checkout token if provided
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    Uri uri = intent.getData();

    String scheme = getString(R.string.web_return_to_scheme);

    if (uri != null && TextUtils.equals(uri.getScheme(), scheme)) {
        webCheckoutInProgress = false;

        // If the app was launched using the scheme, we know we just successfully completed an order
        onCheckoutComplete();

    } else {
        // If a Web checkout was previously launched, we should check its status
        if (webCheckoutInProgress && getSampleApplication().getCheckout() != null) {
            pollCheckoutCompletionStatus(getSampleApplication().getCheckout());
        }
    }
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();

    if (progressDialog != null) {
        progressDialog.dismiss();
    }
}

protected SampleApplication getSampleApplication() {
    return (SampleApplication) getApplication();
}

/**
 * Initializes a simple progress dialog that gets presented while the app is communicating with the server.
 */
private void initializeProgressDialog() {
    if (progressDialog != null) {
        progressDialog.dismiss();
    }

    progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
    progressDialog.setIndeterminate(true);
    progressDialog.setTitle(getString(R.string.please_wait));
    progressDialog.setCancelable(true);
    progressDialog.setOnCancelListener(new DialogInterface.OnCancelListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCancel(DialogInterface dialog) {
            SampleActivity.this.finish();
        }
    });
}

/**
 * Present the progress dialog.
 *
 * @param messageId The identifier (R.string value) of the string to display in the dialog.
 */
protected void showLoadingDialog(final int messageId) {
    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            progressDialog.setMessage(getString(messageId));
            progressDialog.show();
        }
    });
}

protected void dismissLoadingDialog() {
    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            progressDialog.dismiss();
        }
    });
}

protected void onError(RetrofitError error) {
    onError(BuyClient.getErrorBody(error));
}

/**
 * When we encounter an error with one of our network calls, we abort and return to the previous activity.
 * In a production app, you'll want to handle these types of errors more gracefully.
 *
 * @param errorMessage
 */
protected void onError(String errorMessage) {
    progressDialog.dismiss();
    Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Error: " + errorMessage);
    Toast.makeText(this, R.string.error, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    finish();
}

/**
 * Use the latest Checkout objects details to populate the text views in the order summary section.
 */
protected void updateOrderSummary() {
    final Checkout checkout = getSampleApplication().getCheckout();

    if (checkout == null) {
        return;
    }

    ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.line_item_price_value)).setText('$' + checkout.getLineItems().get(0).getPrice());

    double totalDiscount = 0;
    Discount discount = checkout.getDiscount();
    if (discount != null && !TextUtils.isEmpty(discount.getAmount())) {
        totalDiscount += Double.parseDouble(discount.getAmount());
    }
    ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.discount_value)).setText("-$" + Double.toString(totalDiscount));

    double totalGiftCards = 0;
    List<GiftCard> giftCards = checkout.getGiftCards();
    if (giftCards != null) {
        for (GiftCard giftCard : giftCards) {
            if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(giftCard.getAmountUsed())) {
                totalGiftCards += Double.parseDouble(giftCard.getAmountUsed());
            }
        }
    }
    ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.gift_card_value)).setText("-$" + Double.toString(totalGiftCards));
    ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.taxes_value)).setText('$' + checkout.getTotalTax());
    ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.total_value)).setText('$' + checkout.getPaymentDue());

    if (checkout.getShippingRate() != null) {
        ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.shipping_value)).setText('$' + checkout.getShippingRate().getPrice());
    } else {
        ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.shipping_value)).setText("N/A");
    }
}

/**
 * Polls until the web checkout has completed.
 *
 * @param checkout the checkout to check the status on
 */
protected void pollCheckoutCompletionStatus(final Checkout checkout) {
    showLoadingDialog(R.string.getting_checkout_status);

    getSampleApplication().getCheckoutCompletionStatus(new Callback<Boolean>() {
        @Override

        public void success(Boolean complete, Response response) {
            if (complete) {
                dismissLoadingDialog();
                onCheckoutComplete();
            } else {
                pollingHandler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        pollCheckoutCompletionStatus(checkout);
                    }
                }, POLL_DELAY);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void failure(RetrofitError error) {
            onError(error);
        }
    });
}

/**
 * When our polling determines that the checkout is completely processed, show a toast.
 */
private void onCheckoutComplete() {
    dismissLoadingDialog();
    webCheckoutInProgress = false;

    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Toast.makeText(SampleActivity.this, R.string.checkout_complete, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });
}

}
```

This is probably also useful Shopify API Product

```
     package com.shopify.buy.model;

import android.text.TextUtils;

import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.google.gson.GsonBuilder;
import com.google.gson.JsonDeserializationContext;
import com.google.gson.JsonDeserializer;
import com.google.gson.JsonElement;
import com.google.gson.JsonParseException;
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;
import com.shopify.buy.dataprovider.BuyClientFactory;
import com.shopify.buy.utils.DateUtility;
import com.shopify.buy.utils.DateUtility.DateDeserializer;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Date;
import java.lang.reflect.Type;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Set;

/**
 * A {@code Product} is an individual item for sale in a Shopify store.
 */
public class Product extends ShopifyObject {

    @SerializedName("product_id")
    private String productId;

    @SerializedName("channel_id")
    private String channelId;

    private String title;

    private String handle;

    @SerializedName("body_html")
    private String bodyHtml;

    @SerializedName("published_at")
    private Date publishedAtDate;

    @SerializedName("created_at")
    private Date createdAtDate;

    @SerializedName("updated_at")
    private Date updatedAtDate;

    private String vendor;

    @SerializedName("product_type")
    private String productType;

    private List<ProductVariant> variants;

    private List<Image> images;

    private List<Option> options;

    private String tags;

    private Set<String> tagSet;

    private boolean available;

    private boolean published;

    /**
     * @return {@code true} if this product has been published on the store, {@code false} otherwise.
     */
    public boolean isPublished() {
        return published;
    }

    /**
     * @return The unique identifier for this product.
     */
    public String getProductId() {
        return productId;
    }

    /**
     * @return The unique identifier of the Mobile App sales channel for this store.
     */
    public String getChannelId() {
        return channelId;
    }

    /**
     * @return The title of this product.
     */
    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    /**
     * @return The handle of the product. Can be used to construct links to the web page for the product.
     */
    public String getHandle() {
        return handle;
    }

    /**
     * @return The description of the product, complete with HTML formatting.
     */
    public String getBodyHtml() {
        return bodyHtml;
    }

    /**
     * Use {@link #getPublishedAtDate() getPublishedAtDate()}.
     */
    @Deprecated
    public String getPublishedAt() {
        return publishedAtDate == null ? null : DateUtility.createDefaultDateFormat().format(publishedAtDate);
    }

    /**
     * Use {@link #getCreatedAtDate() getCreatedAtDate()}.
     */
    @Deprecated
    public String getCreatedAt() {
        return createdAtDate == null ? null : DateUtility.createDefaultDateFormat().format(createdAtDate);
    }

    /**
     * Use {@link #getUpdatedAtDate() getUpdatedAtDate()}.
     */
    @Deprecated
    public String getUpdatedAt() {
        return updatedAtDate == null ? null : DateUtility.createDefaultDateFormat().format(updatedAtDate);
    }

    /**
     * @return The date this product was published.
     */
    public Date getPublishedAtDate() {
        return publishedAtDate;
    }

    /**
     * @return The date this product was created.
     */
    public Date getCreatedAtDate() {
        return createdAtDate;
    }

    /**
     * @return The date this product was last updated.
     */
    public Date getUpdatedAtDate() {
        return updatedAtDate;
    }

    /**
     * @return The name of the vendor of this product.
     */
    public String getVendor() {
        return vendor;
    }

    /**
     * @return The categorization that this product was tagged with, commonly used for filtering and searching.
     */
    public String getProductType() {
        return productType;
    }

    /**
     * @return A list of additional categorizations that a product can be tagged with, commonly used for filtering and searching. Each tag has a character limit of 255.
     */
    public Set<String> getTags() { return tagSet; }

    /**
     * @return A list {@link ProductVariant} objects, each one representing a different version of this product.
     */
    public List<ProductVariant> getVariants() {
        return variants;
    }

    /**
     * @return A list of {@link Image} objects, each one representing an image associated with this product.
     */
    public List<Image> getImages() {
        return images;
    }

    /**
     * @return {code true} if this product has at least one image, {@code false} otherwise.
     */
    public boolean hasImage() {
        return images != null && !images.isEmpty();
    }

    /**
     * @return A list of {@link Option} objects, which can be used to select a specific {@link ProductVariant}.
     */
    public List<Option> getOptions() {
        return options;
    }

    /**
     * @return {@code true} if this product is in stock and available for purchase, {@code false} otherwise.
     */
    public boolean isAvailable() { return available; }

    /**
     * For internal use only.
     */
    public boolean hasDefaultVariant() {
        return variants != null && variants.size() == 1 && variants.get(0).getTitle().equals("Default Title");
    }

    /**
     * Returns the {@code Image} for the {@code ProductVariant} with the given id
     * @param variant the {@link ProductVariant} to find the {@link Image}
     * @return the {@link Image} corresponding to the {@link ProductVariant} if one was found, otherwise the {@code Image} for the {@link Product}.  This may return null if no applicable images were found.
     */
    public Image getImage(ProductVariant variant) {
        if (variant == null) {
            throw new NullPointerException("variant cannot be null");
        }

        List<Image> images = getImages();

        if (images == null || images.size() < 1) {
            // we did not find any images
            return null;
        }

        for (Image image : images) {
            if (image.getVariantIds() != null && image.getVariantIds().contains(variant.getId())) {
                return image;
            }
        }

        // The variant did not have an image, use the default image in the Product
        return images.get(0);
    }

    /**
     * @param optionValues  A list of {@link OptionValue} objects that represent a specific variant selection.
     * @return  The {@link ProductVariant} that matches the given list of the OptionValues, or {@code null} if no such variant exists.
     */
    public ProductVariant getVariant(List<OptionValue> optionValues) {
        if (optionValues == null) {
            return null;
        }

        int numOptions = optionValues.size();
        for (ProductVariant variant : variants) {
            for (int i = 0; i < numOptions; i++) {
                if (!variant.getOptionValues().get(i).getValue().equals(optionValues.get(i).getValue())) {
                    break;
                } else if (i == numOptions - 1) {
                    return variant;
                }
            }
        }

        return null;
    }

    public static class ProductDeserializer implements JsonDeserializer<Product> {

        @Override
        public Product deserialize(JsonElement json, Type typeOfT, JsonDeserializationContext context) throws JsonParseException {
            return fromJson(json.toString());
        }

    }

    /**
     * A product object created using the values in the JSON string.
     */
    public static Product fromJson(String json) {
        Gson gson = BuyClientFactory.createDefaultGson(Product.class);

        Product product = gson.fromJson(json, Product.class);

        List<ProductVariant> variants = product.getVariants();

        if (variants != null) {
            for (ProductVariant variant : variants) {
                variant.productId = Long.parseLong(product.productId);
                variant.productTitle = product.getTitle();
            }
        }

        // Create the tagSet.
        product.tagSet = new HashSet<>();

        // Populate the tagSet from the comma separated list.
        if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(product.tags)) {
            for (String tag : product.tags.split(",")) {
                String myTag = tag.trim();
                product.tagSet.add(myTag);
            }
        }

        return product;
    }

    }
```

simple_list_item.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
android:padding="@dimen/spacing_16dp"
android:textColor="@android:color/black"
android:textSize="@dimen/text_large">
</TextView>
```